# Easy SQL statement - Should I JOIN 3 tables here or 2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm a newbie to MySQL and php and I'm getting wrapped around the axle on this one. I've been working on this for hours and can't get the desired result. Help please? What I am starting with is:

```
$query = sprintf('select image_id, filename from images');
$result = mysql_query($query);
$images = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id = $row['image_id'];
    $images[$id] = $row['filename'];
    echo $images[$id];
}
```

I have three tables:

1. submissions - submission_id,  price, description
2. images - image_id, filename, size
3. imagsub -   image_id, submission_id

The above script is pulling out all the filenames and image_id's in the database. I need to limit the results to just the images rows that match up with the submission_id's in the referencing table. Ive tried various JOINS within the sprintf function to no avail and now I cant even get the results I want with a simple mysql_query. Can someone please set me on the right path before I pull my hair out. Do I need to JOIN all three tables here or is it enough to JOIN the images and imagsub tables? I have the submission_id I need in a variable called $item that was pulled from a previous page so maybe I don't need the submissions table at all, just the foreign key from imagsub?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just went with the first response and it worked great. There was another piece later in the code I was missing that was completely throwing me off so your advice put me on the right track. I ended up with:

Comment: <?php
    $query = mysql_query("select images.image_id, images.filename from images
  join imagsub on images.image_id = imagsub.image_id
  where imagsub.submission_id = '$item'");
    
    $images = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id = $row['image_id'];
        $images[$id] = $row['filename'];
  echo $images[$id];
    }
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
select image_id, filename from images
  join imagsub on images.image_id = imagsub.image_id
  where imagesub.submission_id = YourID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select image_id, filename from images i
  join imagesub s on s.image_id = i.image_id
  where s.subbmision_id = $1;
```

You will need to set the $1 parameter to the "$item" value you received in the request.

Answer (score 0):

try this as the query to get all of them

```
select s.submission_id, b.image_id, i.filename
from submissions s 
inner join imagsub b on b.submission_id = s.submission_id
inner join images i on i.image_id = b.image_id
```